# tsc not excluding npm linked node_modules

Tags: typescript, npm, symlink

**The problem:** When type checking my app using `tsc` I am getting errors for `npm link`ed modules.

Here is my type-check command:
`"type-check": "tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.json"`

and here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
        //"importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"
    },
    "exclude": ["./node_modules/*"] // I've also tried node_modules, /node_modules, node_modules/
}
```

The command will fail due to type errors in one of my node_modules which is connected via npm link.

Any way to exclude this module from type check

---

**Edit:**

I have also tried using a double globstar (`**`) e.g.

```json
"exclude": ["./node_modules/**/*"]
```

and this gives me the same incorrect result.

Comment: Double-check that tsc exists in your node_modules/.bin. If not - try and identify where it takes it from.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem. I'm facing the same one. I have a lib linked with npm link and tsc is no excluding such lib when type checking/compiling.

Comment: Can't say i did :-/

Comment: could you try this ? "exclude": ["***/node_modules/**/*"]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using webpack try to add `symlinks: false` in resolve. That solved similar issue for me.

```
resolve: {
    // ...  
    symlinks: false,
},
```

If you are using purely `tsc` try (I haven't tried this):

```
preserveSymlinks: true
```

Comment: `preserveSymlinks: true` in tsconfig.json worked for me, thanks!